# SQLite - update table to number rows sequentially

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Scan
(Id Integer,
Ordinal Integer)

INSERT Scan VALUES(10, 1)
INSERT Scan VALUES(20, 1)
INSERT Scan VALUES(30, 8)
INSERT Scan VALUES(40, 10)
```

I'd like to update Ordinal column so all the numbers become sequential like so(in case of duplicate Ordinal order by Id):

```
Id Ordinal
10 1
20 2
30 3
40 4
```

Is it possible with plain SQL in SQLite?

Comment: `update scan set ordinal = id` ???

Comment: You should read http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1 which is titled How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field.

Comment: Id field IS Auto-increment. Ordinal have to be without "holes". I give Id as example just to illustrate if for some reason I have duplicate Ordinals - it should sort by Id during update. When I fill in table - Ordinals populated correctly. I want to delete record and then RESET whole table so ordinals renumber. I can do it one by one and it will work(very few records) but in SQL Server it's done easy and I thought there is a trick in SQLite to do this

Answer (score 4):

SQLite doesn't really have a good way of doing this.  Here is one approach that isn't particularly efficient:

```
update scan
    set ordinal = (select count(*)
                   from scan s2
                   where s2.ordinal < scan.ordinal or
                         s2.ordinal = scan.ordinal and s2.id <= scan.id
                  );
```

Comment: Getting error running this: `near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Scan s SET Ordinal = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Scan s2 WHERE s2.Ordinal < s.Ordinal OR s2.Ordinal = s.Ordinal AND s2._id <= s._id);`

Comment: You're using a different statement, the problem is that you can not use alias in update itself in sqllite so  `update scan s` is not supported. Remove `s` alias and use the query as it is provided by @GordonLinoff